# Import UIkit Angular FullStack

Tags: javascript, angular-fullstack, getuikit

I'm getting this error trying to import UIkit with Angular FullStack generator:

```
Module 'uikit' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

This is what I've done:

**webpack.make.js**

```
    if(TEST) {
        config.entry = {};
    } else {
        config.entry = {
            app: './client/app/app.js',
            polyfills: './client/polyfills.js',
            vendor: [
                'angular',
                'angular-animate',
                'angular-aria',
                'angular-cookies',
                'angular-resource',

                'angular-sanitize',


                'angular-ui-router',
                'lodash',

                'uikit'
            ]
        };
    }
```

**app.js**

```
...
import uikit from 'uikit';
...

angular.module('myApp', [ngCookies, ngResource, ngSanitize, uiRouter, uikit])
```

However, I can use the style directives by adding the following to my app.scss:

```
@import'~uikit/dist/css/uikit.css';
```

But, if I don't import the JS module, I get `UIkit is not defined`.

How can I properly import UIkit to my project??

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: have you tried `import UIkit from 'uikit';` ? Of course css will work, but not sure about js plugins.It works with Vue and React, but not a world about Angular in docs.

Comment: @cssBlaster21895, if I import it as you say, I get this new error: `Failed to instantiate module function plugin(UIkit) due to:
[$injector:strictdi] plugin is not using explicit annotation and cannot be invoked in strict mode` and the page turns blank...

Comment: so it seems UIkit is not angular friendly. Its code misses annotation. Maybe you could try with https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-annotate-webpack-plugin, or https://github.com/huston007/ng-annotate-loader. But I think it could be hard way. Javascript rather wont work, at last you can import css/scss.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following the [docs](https://getuikit.com/docs/webpack), this is what worked for me:

1. Do **not** add uikit vendor to webpack.make.js
2. Insert `import UIkit from 'uikit';` to my app.js